# Show divs whith JQuery every 1 sec

Tags: jquery

I have ten divs with "box" class. I want to show one after other.
I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".box").each( function() {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
    });
});
```

...but all are displayed at the same time.
How can i do it? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use the "duration" parameter of `fadeTo`.  Currently you are passing "fast" for each one.  That is not (necessarily) one second and it is the same amount of time for each element.  Instead, pass a specific time (in milliseconds) and pass a different time for each element.

You can use the `index` parameter passed to the callback function of `each` for this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".box").each( function(i) {
        $(this).fadeTo(1000 * i, 1);
    });
});
```

Alternatively, if you want each duration to be fast, but to space them out, you could do this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".box").each( function(i) {
        $(this).delay(1000 * i).fadeTo("fast", 1);
    });
});
```

Using `delay` here will cause the `fadeTo` to be delayed by the number of milliseconds passed.